# I getException in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Code:

```
WebElement betting = driver.findElement(By.id("flex-menu"));
        List<WebElement> hallo = betting.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='flex-menu']//ul//li//a"));

            System.out.println(hallo.get(0).getText());

            hallo.get(0).click();
```

Error Massage:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException:
>
> Session ID: 4bfaaf77-6275-4ffc-a8d7-b24b70f3acca  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:279)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:83)
>     at Aufgabe1.Main.main(Main.java:41)

What is wrong with that Code? I cant Click but it found the Element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver throws "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not visible" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690971/selenium-webdriver-throws-exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-elemen)

Answer (score 1):

It could be because of two reasons.

1) Your button element is visible but not yet clickable. If that is the case use wait condition.

```
WebDriverWait myWaitVar = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
WebElement el = myWaitVar.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(betting.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='flex-menu']//ul//li//a")).get(0)));
el.click();
```

2) If element is hidden/overlapped by some other element use JavascriptExecutor

```
 WebDriverWait myWaitVar = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    WebElement el = myWaitVar.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(betting.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='flex-menu']//ul//li//a")).get(0)));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el);
```

More information is available in 
[In Selenium Webdriver, ExpectedCondition.elementToBeClickable is not waiting until the progress bar disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673465/in-selenium-webdriver-expectedcondition-elementtobeclickable-is-not-waiting-unt)

Answer (score 0):

That may be because the element you are trying is hided/needs implicit wait conditions. try to use .enable() function implement implicit- explicit wait conditions and then try to use .click() function.